# Continuing the most outer loop from the most nested one

Tags: loops, nested-loops, abap

Is there a way to continue the most outer loop from the most nested one in ABAP?

Example in Java. There is a construct in this language using labels (most people do not know of it anyway) which allows me to continue the most outer loop from the nested one.

```java
public class NestedLoopContinue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        label1: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                if (i == 3) {
                    continue label1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
1
2
3
5
```

Now, how can I do it in ABAP in a smart way? One solution would be to use `TRY. ENDTRY.` block but it is rather a hacking one. Any other ideas?

```
DATA: l_outer_counter TYPE i.
DO 5 TIMES.
  l_outer_counter = sy-index.
  TRY.
    DO 2 TIMES.
      IF l_outer_counter = 4.
        RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE cx_abap_random.
      ENDIF.
    ENDDO.
    WRITE / l_outer_counter.
    CATCH cx_abap_random.
      CONTINUE.
  ENDTRY.
ENDDO.
```

Or maybe there is a way to tell whether the `DO. ENDO.` ended with an `EXIT` statement (without introducing an own variable of course, like `SYST` global variable)?

```
DATA: l_outer_counter TYPE i.
DO 5 TIMES.
  l_outer_counter = sy-index.
  DO 2 TIMES.
    IF l_outer_counter = 4.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.
  IF sy-last_loop_ended_with_exit = abap_true. "???
    CONTINUE.
  ENDIF.
  WRITE / l_outer_counter.
ENDDO.
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what would be the practical application of this?

Comment: @vwegert Yes, there is a practical application. In fact I use `LOOP AT`. The outer loop I have contains objects, the inner one contains the references to implementations of the same interface which method I call with the identifiers obtained from the outer loop. Based on the result of a method call I want to proceed to the next outer loop object or continue normally with the rest of the inner loop and what is before the outer `ENDLOOP`.

Comment: I edited the question. The way to tell whether there was `EXIT` involved in ending the loop (maybe one of the `SY` flags?) would also be quite a nice alternative in this case. Then a `CONTINUE` based on this flag would be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the application, but you might want to take a look at meshes (http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abaptypes_mesh.htm) - they were added recently...

Comment: Can someone comment on why this question is getting downvoted?

Comment: @robjohncox: guess this is the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting) effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with nested loops, I often find the best way to improve readability, and avoid using more unusual approaches (such as breaking to a label, which is not only controversial because of its goto-like nature, but also reduces readability because a lot of people are not familiar with them) is to extract the inner loop into a separate function. I do not know how this is done in ABAP, but the refactored Java equivalent would be:

```java
public class NestedLoopContinue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            NestedLoopContinue.innerLoop(i)
        }
    }

    static void innerLoop(int i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (i == 3) {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i + 1);
    }
}
```

I would argue that in this example, this actually becomes less readable because it is harder to follow the logic across the two methods. However, if this was a real-world example (where the methods and variables had some actual meanings and appropriate names to go with them), then the result of extracting the inner loop into a separate method would be more readable than using a label.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know of an ABAP-specific solution, but I've used a general programming solution to handle this before; simply use a boolean and check at the end of the inner loop whether or not to continue.

In Java:

```java
public class NestedLoopContinue
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            boolean earlyBreak = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    earlyBreak = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (earlyBreak)
            {
               continue;
            }
            System.out.println(i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And in ABAP:

```
DATA: l_outer_counter type i,
      early_break type FLAG.

DO 5 TIMES.
  l_outer_counter = sy-index.

  DO 2 TIMES.
      IF l_outer_counter = 4.
       early_break = ABAP_TRUE.
       EXIT.
      ENDIF.
  ENDDO.

  IF early_break = ABAP_TRUE.
      CLEAR early_break.
      CONTINUE.
  ENDIF.

  WRITE / l_outer_counter.

ENDDO.
```

I've read that the reason label-based breaks exist in Java in the first place is because `GOTO` statements explicitly do not, and the case covered by label-based break was one of the few "good" uses of `GOTO` that the team wanted to maintain.

In general, though, this is a very awkward construction. Is there no potential way to refactor your code (perhaps swapping the inner-ness of the loops) to remove the need for this in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [robjohncox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1980029/robjohncox) answer, the ABAP code might look like this.

```
CLASS lcl_nested_loop_continue DEFINITION FINAL.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      inner_loop
        IMPORTING
          i_index TYPE i.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_nested_loop_continue IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DO 5 TIMES.
      lcl_nested_loop_continue=>inner_loop( sy-index ).
    ENDDO.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD inner_loop.
    DO 2 TIMES.
      IF i_index = 4.
        RETURN.
      ENDIF.
    ENDDO.
    WRITE / i_index.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```